# How can I debug mvc scaffolding Text Template file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, t4

I add Custom scaffolding file  as CustomCreate.tt .In mvc add view dialog when I select my Custom template  in dialog I have an error .how can I debug  my Text template file?

Answer (score 2):

## If you use a version of Visual Studio < VS 2012

You can try the following:

1. Include the System.Diagnostics namespace in your .tt file (`<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>`)
2. Put a try-catch around the code that you are attempting to generate, and output eny exceptions to `Trace.TraceError`
3. If you run the template and an error occurs, the error details should appear in your Visual Studio Console Window.

You can look at the following as an example:

```
<#@ template language="C#" HostSpecific="True" #>
<#@ output extension="cs" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerRootName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="Namespace" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="AreaName" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
<#        try{  #>
namespace <#=            Namespace #>
{
    public class <#=            ControllerName #> : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: <#=            (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(AreaName)) ? ("/" + AreaName) : String.Empty #>/<#=            ControllerRootName #>/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}

<# }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Trace.TraceError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
#>
```

Notice that the try-catch block surrounds all of the templating code for the class.

## If you use a version of Visual Studio >= VS 2012

A better way to debug your T4 template is to add breakpoints, as with normal CSharp and VB code.  To run the debugger on your T4 template simply right-click it in the solution explorer and select **Debug T4 Template** from the context menu.

The following article will also help you to solve common T4 issues:
[Debugging a T4 Text Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126247.aspx)

Notice that this is only available for VS2012 and up.  As such, the first method I mentioned will be suitable for developers using older versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: when I got error in custom view creation.a error page show me the exception ...I want set breakepoint in my CustomCreate.tt and check my codes

Comment: @M.Azad Please see updated answer.  What you want to do is only possible with Visual Studio 2012 or higher.  If you are using an older version, I would suggest that you use Trace.TraceInformation to surface the value of variables at certain points in your code.

Comment: @M.Azad Were you able to debug your T4 template?